# How to send Kernel name in udev rules?

Tags: usb, kernel, mount, udev

I want to do is auto mount every usb-drive to static path.
But when I send kernel name with %k to shell script it returns like 1-3, 2-4 ... not sdc1, sdd1... s[b-z][1-9]

this is my udev rules 10-local.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ACTION=="add",SYMLINK+="usb_%k",RUN+="/home/etc/udev-mount.sh %k "
ACTION=="remove",SUBSYSTEM=="usb",RUN+="/home/etc/udev-umount.sh %k"
~                                                                               
~
```

and shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

DEVICE=$1


mkdir -p /app/$DEVICE

mount /dev/$DEVICE /app/$DEVICE
```

I'm using UBUNTU 16.04

please help me..

Comment: and when I set symlink to some label and mount it to other path it said 
"mount:  /dev/bus/usb/001/023 is not a block device"

Comment: It just mount /dev/sdd1 /other/path, it mounted well...

Comment: Excellent reference on what OP is trying to accomplish: https://superuser.com/a/64970/662962

Comment: Thank you, But I just want how to get kernel name like sda1...  not 1-3, That references doesn't answer it.

Comment: True but in the reference it appears to be working properly using `%k` argument. I haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just usinig %k in udev rules for params... it returns 1-1. Can you tell me how to using %k properly..?

Comment: Sorry I've never used `%k` option in `udev`. When I plug in USB flash drive it gets auto-mounted to `/media` directory and I don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

- Actually, you are getting the right kernel name using `%k` and it is passed to the script.
- However, your rule condition is blind `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` , it filters other device nodes other than the ones you want (partition devices).

  Take a look on UDEV manpage, like the difference `SUBSYSTEM=..` vs `SUBSYSTEMS=..` , use `udevadm info -a ..` to get more info for condition.
- You may use this simple one

  ```
  ..,KERNEL="sd[a-z][0-9]*",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",..
  ```